# Upload files to document library with file properties

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, metadata

I am using the following script in powershell to copy documents from a file directory to a Document library:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
 }

$siteCollUrl = "http://sharepoint"
$libraryName = "Documents"
#Physical/Network location of files
$reportFilesLocation  = "C:\docs"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$libraryName];

if($spSourceList -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "The Library $libraryName could not be found."
    return;
}

$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $reportFilesLocation)).GetFiles()
foreach($file in $files)
{
    #Open file
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

    #Add file
    $folder =  $spSourceWeb.getfolder($libraryName)

    Write-Host "Copying file $file to $libraryName..."
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)

    #Close file stream
    $fileStream.Close();
}
$spSourceWeb.dispose();
Write-Host "Files have been uploaded to $libraryName."
```

The created by / modified column are set by default as the user that runs the script, but every document (.doc/.pdf./etc) has the property 'owner'. How to extract this and set the appropriate column to this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the owner of the file say `test.txt` - for a single file - using the below command:

```
Get-Acl D:\Scripts\Test.txt | Select-Object Owner
```

for multiple files within a folder/subfolder, you can use :

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Scripts -recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}
```

You can incorporate the above in your PS code.